# Android Style Date Picker and Time Picker for API Lower Than 21

Tags: android, datepicker, styles, timepicker

How to style date picker and time picker to change text color? I am not using TimePickerDialog or DatePickerDialog instead i created my own dialog fragment and it has view pager with time and date picker and they are located in xml file separately. And I can't change color of the text on both of them for api level lower than 21.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code worked for me to style picker by passing theme wrapper to layout inflater.

Context contextThemeWrapper = new ContextThemeWrapper(
                context,
                android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light);

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    LayoutInflater localInflater = inflater.cloneInContext(contextThemeWrapper);
    View rootView = localInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_timepicker, container, false);
```